# Trying to read large csv using pandas but process is getting killed in between

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, amazon-ec2

I have a large file on my ubuntu EC2 instance. I am trying to read that large csv file using pandas. But the process is getting killed in between.
And after that I can't access any file or run any command on the instance.
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
This is the message that gets displayed after the process is killed and I try to access anything on the instance.

However, when I try to read the same file using python line by line, I can read the file.

I thought this might be the space issue but the file size is 83Gb and the free space on my instance is 160Gb.

Comment: You realise that `pandas.read_csv` attempts to read the *entire* file into a `pandas.DataFrame` all into memory? So unless you've got something like 100gb of RAM spare - it's definitely going to fall over.

Comment: Depending what you want to do with the data - the solutions are varied. It might help get a relevant answer if you could elaborate on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: file size on disk is *not* an accurate indicator of it's space usage in memory. "Cannot allocate memory" on the other hand, is exceptionally clear. Your file, when being read into memory, is taking up all resources available.

Comment: Use Dask or Pyspark.
Here there is a guy procesing an HDF5 file with over a billion rows using Dask: It is in Spanish though
https://youtu.be/-1ZgP9yN51c

Comment: @JonClements So I have this 83Gb file which actually contains 20M data with 47 different columns. I wish to reduce the file size by reading into a data frame and consequently breaking the data from different data frames to new csv files.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh so what should I do in such a case to achieve my objective?

Comment: @LanguageTech let me check this. Thank you!